# Eclipse Plug-in:Focus lost after activating a view via (controlSite.doVerb(OLE.OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE));

Tags: eclipse-plugin, ole

I have a view which is initialised via OleControlSite and invoked via OleAutomation. It is actually a media player which I call in a view after user right clicks the file and calls Play in the context menu. Whenever I play a file by first right clicking and calling Play, it plays absolutely fine.  The problem is when user displays the view before doing a right click(Window->Show View->Other->MyView) and then tries to do a right click and Play, at this point of time ISelection returns null and hence nothing plays.

```
 IWorkbenchPage iwPage=PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
             ISelection selection=iwPage.getSelection();
```

The problem is the selections somehow loses focus if the view has been invoked in the fashion described.

This is how the view is initialised when the plugin is loaded

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        frame = new OleFrame(parent, SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        //      OleControlSite controlSite;
        try {
            controlSite = new OleControlSite(frame, SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL,"WMPlayer.OCX.7");
            controlSite.doVerb(OLE.OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE);           
            oleAutomation = new OleAutomation(controlSite);
            makeActions();
            fillActionBars();           

        } catch (SWTException ex) {

            MessageBox box = new MessageBox(getSite().getShell(),SWT.ICON_INFORMATION);         
            box.setMessage("Failed to Initialise Media Player.");
            box.setText("Error");
            box.open();                     
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way where we can force the focus to the Project Explorer where the current file is selected ?